# How to Include External JavaScript Libraries In An Angular 4 TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, implementation

I try implemented my angular project [this](https://github.com/imgix/drift) js lib but it's doesn't work. How to implement 3rd party js libs Angular 4 project and how to use in my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it just like how they say in the instructions. In project directory:

```
npm install drift-zoom --save
```

then add this to the component you want to use it in:

```
import Drift from 'drift-zoom';
```

then whenever you want to call it, just use:

```
const draft = new Draft('whatever params you need');
```

Comment: I try this and more its return all time `new Drift` requires a DOM element as its first argument.

Comment: Yes. You need to pass it a DOM element. That's how drift works. I don't understand your question.

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1gmkp) i create this sample its works here but my app inside component doestn work. I set it DOM element @ViewChild or document.querySelector but its not accept it. Return all time "TypeError: `new Drift` requires a DOM element as its first argument." this error.